# Difficulties with Importing PDFs in Mathematica

Tags: import, pdf-format

I am trying to import a group of PDFs that I have downloaded (it is in the realm of 1,000+). They are a group of doctoral dissertations that I'm trying to automatically extract bibliographic information from. They open perfectly in Preview and Adobe Acrobat Reader. Unfortunately, when I go to `Import[]` them, I receive the following errors like so:

```
Import["1997-01.pdf","Elements"]

Import::general: Expected cross reference table >>
Import::general: Expected cross reference table >>
Import::general: Could not find document trailer >>
General::stop: Further output of Import::general will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

I have never encountered this with `Elements` before, which is normally my first step in figuring out how to tackle a file. The same holds for `Plaintext`, etc. If I `Import["1997-01.pdf","Text"]` it generates a file akin to this:

```
%PDF-1.2
%BHIL-SC:0014503155,00391,00004,00008,00399,00790,00004,00004,00009,00400,00791,00004,00004,00010,00401,00792,00004 ... etc. etc.
```

The file itself is downloaded from an online repository, however, but is of high quality.

[image]

My end goal is to try `TextRecognize[]` on it, but I cannot even get to that stage. Does *Mathematica* offer any workarounds for PDFs like this? FWIW, the PDF claims that I have full permissions to edit, alter, etc., but there is no built-in text layer.

--- Edited to Clarify ---

The PDF is version 1.2. It is an image layer, not a text layer. Hope that this helps!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you worked this out?

Comment: @CHM I have. I'm using Automator to take each PDF, split it into individual files, and then converting it to a JPEG. I then use Mathematica to import the JPEG, `TextRecognize[]` it, and have begun crunching the information that way. It's a painstakingly slow process in terms of computing time, but all pretty automated.

Comment: @ianmilligan I suggest to you `GIF 600 DPI`. I've had better results with that than with `JPG 600 DPI` and `TIFF 600 DPI` as well as smaller filesizes than `TIFF`. Mind going to the chatroom?

Comment: I suspect the file(s) may benefit from being processed by Adobe Acrobat Pro, specifically, its Recognize Text option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's really scanned images, then you could try this:

```
pages = Import["yourfile.pdf", {"PDF", "Images"}]
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest running the file through `ghostscript` or another distiller to clean up the potentially malformed PDF code first. The command would look like this:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newfile.pdf badfile.pdf
```

**Edit**

Since you mentioned that you're on Mac OS X and also appear to be able to view the PDF file in Preview.app, there is an even simpler way:

If you're on Lion: Open the PDF in Preview, and export it as multipage `TIFF`. This can be done under the `File > Export` menu. The resulting file can be imported in Mathematica and yields a list of images.

Another possible approach that works for all OS X versions is to open the PDF in Preview and print it to a file. With that method, you could also select only the pages you really need by highlighting them in the Thumbnail view, and then choosing `File > Print Selected Pages...`. The PDF-printed file would hopefully have been processed to get rid of the errors.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The command returns the same error `Import::general : Expected cross reference table >>`. I will look into `ghostscript`, I have never used it before.

Comment: OK - since it looks like you need it, I've added more specific info on ghostscript. I'm using it on Mac OS X, but it's cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks, Jens. This is great and will save me hours upon hours of work. I'm also on OS X so this would be perfect.

Comment: @Ian, I realized that as a Mac user you have some more "manual" options that could be useful, see the edit above.

Comment: These are cool. This will motivate me to learn Automator or something else to make this a quicker process.

Comment: @Jens I've tried to use the `gs` command you've given above, but it doesn't work. GS can't open my `device`, it says.

Comment: @CHM not knowing any details, I can only suggest to try  using `-sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=newfile.ps` instead. I've been a ghostscript package maintainer for several years, but I can't tell much from the error message you quoted without knowing version, platform, example, etc.

Comment: @Jens May I invite you to visit the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)?

Comment: @CHM FWIW, the `gs` command failed on my PDFs as well (I think they're just crippled documents), but @Jen's suggestion to go through Preview and convert to an image worked really well.

Comment: @CHM sorry I didn't have any more have time to respond today.

Comment: @Masi It works fine for me. I can't say anything about your OS. Make sure you have a recent version of ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

In the command line on linux (I am using fedora 20), try:

```
pdftotext PDFFILE.pdf NEWFILE.txt
```

Then in *Mathematica*:

```
variable = Import[NEWFILE.txt, #] & /@  
  {"Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5"};
```

where "Element1..." are the elements obtained by

```
Import [NEWFILE.txt, "Elements"]
```

Then you can examine the `variable` using part:

```
var[[   SOME INDEX OPERATION  ]]
```

Comment: on fedora if you dont have pdftotext try: sudo yum install pdftotext

Comment: after you do this there we go you have your data ready for string manipulation using regular expressions to find references or just use Perl