# Can not Import PDF

Tags: import, pdf-format

I try to import PDF and extract text from it

```
Import["D:\\Vegetarian MS.pdf", {"PDF", "Plaintext"}]
```

but with some files I have a problem like this

```
Import::general: Unimplemented operator ' encountered >>

Import::general: Could not draw page 1 stream 0 >>

Import::general: Could not draw page 1 >>
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you

link to file
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15137276/Vegetarian%20MS.pdf

Comment: I'd try to reprocess the PDF using some tool that can do this (GhostScript's pdf2pdf, xpdf (??), Multivalent (get the older version),pdftk,  or if you have it: Acrobat).  Then you can try importing again and hope it works.  Or just use one of these tools to extract the text from the PDF.

Comment: I used Acrobat and saved it as optimized pdf. It imports fine that way.

Comment: Printing to CutePDF made for an importable file, but text was slightly garbled.

Comment: I extract text with xpdf.

Comment: Thanks all.

Just I used to run Mathematica script that extract text from a set of files through all subdirectory

Comment: on OS X (on which clearly you are not) you can open the pdf in the built-in Preview pdf viewer, then save it and then it's readable by mathematica.

Comment: Try `Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15137276/Vegetarian%20MS.pdf", {{"Title"}}]` for a hint of what is going on. BTW Google says the translation is: "Tick ​​to climb the most climbed Han stern the Hyuk bowl countenance Ben open 䴀 the uniform"

Comment: A very similar question, but for OS X, is here: [Difficulties with Importing PDFs in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2781/245)

Comment: @belisarius it's funny as for English lessons)